# Select all rows where dates fall between start column and end column in table 1 AND where the session user has eventID's that match from table 2

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this is too complicated for a SELECT alone or if it should be done in PHP.

I have two tables: EventDetail and EventPersonnel.  I need to return the events for a specific date range and user.

**EventDetail**

> ```
> EventId | EventName | Start      | End
> ------: | :-------- | :--------- | :---------
>       1 | Event A   | 2022-03-09 | 2022-03-11
>       2 | Event B   | 2022-03-09 | 2022-03-15
>       3 | Event C   | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-21
> ```

**EventPersonnel**

> ```
> EventID | UserID
> ------: | -----:
>       1 |      1
>       1 |      3
>       2 |      2
>       3 |      1
>       3 |      2
>       3 |      3
> ```

**Expected Results:**

If today were March 10, 2022 and current userId = 1, the expected results are:

> ```
> EventId | EventName | StartDate  | EndDate   
> ------: | :-------- | :--------- | :---------
>       1 | Event A   | 2022-03-09 | 2022-03-11
>       3 | Event C   | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e058c4c29b358a3608faebbe891319f)*

I solved the first part returning all of the rows in where the current date falls between the start date and end date in my eventDetails table as below:

```
$currentEvent = new WA_MySQLi_RS("currentEvent",$stapleton,1);
$currentEvent->setQuery("SELECT * FROM eventDetails WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN start AND end");
$currentEvent->execute();
```

I can also return all of the records of the logged in user via the session:

```
$userEvent = new WA_MySQLi_RS("userEvent",$stapleton,0);
$userEvent->setQuery("SELECT eventID FROM eventPersonnel WHERE userID = ?");
$userEvent->bindParam("i", "".($_SESSION['UserID'])  ."", "-1"); //colname
$userEvent->execute();
```

Both of these work as i need them. However there is one more piece I need and that is to combine them so that I am only returning the events for the logged in user. I have tried several subqueries and cannot come up with anything that is not a illegal SQL error.

I don't know if I am explaining it well enough. I don't believe this would be hard for someone knowing what they are doing. But I don't know where to start.

I am very new to Php and can echo the queries and can create repeat regions to show my results but I do not know where to begin to write proper code. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me the proper code AND if they could please tell me what I need to learn so I can understand this myself. There's SO MUCH out there that for a noob like myself I have no clue even where to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM eventDetails ed, eventPersonnel ep
WHERE  ep.userID = ? 
AND ed.eventID = ep.eventID
AND CURDATE() BETWEEN ed.start AND ed.end` ?

Comment: Remove the useless quotes and parentheses `"".($_SESSION['UserID'])  .""`

Comment: SparKot - thank you! I had tried just about every way possible using AND including that I believe but I guess I must have mistyped something or screwed up the aliases. At least I know I'm not crazy and this is possible.

Comment: Dharman - Thanks for the tip. I obviously have syntax issues. Not sure if the stuff I've picked up is old or simply wrong. Could you point me to a reference or version that would help me learn the correct way? Thanks again!

Comment: Since this is primarily a SQL question, it would be better to post your actual table structure with some sample data, rather than "describing" it :-) .  Posting DDL + DML statements takes far less time and removes any guesswork on our part.  Here's a [starter db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e058c4c29b358a3608faebbe891319f), modify it as needed   Use the "markdown" link to generate formatted code you can paste into your question. Also, always include your MySQL version in any sql any questions, as functionality varies by version

Comment: Another useful tool for sharing http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Also, if you're new to sql see this high level [overview of sql JOINs](https://database.guide/sql-joins-tutorial/).

Comment: SOS - this is very helpful! Thanks, this will help me learn more and when I do have questions make them easier to ask.

Comment: You're welcome. It's never too late to edit and improve the question. I modified it to demonstrate what info to include in a sql question (just as an example).  Though FWIW SparKot already answered your question :)